# Как сделать команду Embed

Tags: python, discord.py

Всем привет, я новичок по Discord.py, и хочу у вас спросить, как сделать команду Embed? Пишет человек например !embed Привет (это титул), привет как дела? (это описание), синий (это цвет). Буду благодарен если поможете.

Answer (score 1):

```
@commands.command()
async def embed(self, ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed()
    embed.color = discord.Color.blurple
    embed.set_author(name=ctx.author.name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
    embed.title = 'title'
    embed.description = "description"
    embed.add_field(name='field name', value='field value')
    embed.add_field(name='field name', value='field value')
    embed.add_field(name='field name', value='field value', inline=False)
    embed.set_thumbnail(url='https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/Wvjx6rVlC1rGWKkln3r-23ICKV--sxEEUuq7jd15BeJan8v-wS7TGwm0NHXqqon18w')
    embed.set_image(url='https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/Wvjx6rVlC1rGWKkln3r-23ICKV--sxEEUuq7jd15BeJan8v-wS7TGwm0NHXqqon18w')
    embed.set_footer(text='text', icon_url='example.com')
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Пример всего `embed`

**[Документация](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=embed#discord.Embed)**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а команда embed, а аргументы какие писать?

Comment: я же не указывал аргументы